# Is it possible to convert Ikea crib to an adult sofa/couch?

Tags: furniture, design, weight-capacity, planning

I was planning to buy a second-hand [Ikea Crib](https://www.ikea.com/ca/en/p/sundvik-crib-gray-50494080/) and turn it into a couch. However, the crib's maximum load is 50lb - which is way too low for any fully grown people to use. Is it possible to add reinforcements and increase the maximum load to at least 270lb? If so, how/what methods can we use to reinforce it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. This type of query isn't a good fit for the format here. The basic answer would seem to be a yes, because you could add any amount of wood (or metal) to the underside to reinforce/stiffen as needed. But whether the overall structure could be strengthened sufficiently is highly questionable. And also there are far too many variables we don't know, including tools, budget, your location, and not least your experience, for a useful Answer to be provided.

Comment: Obviously you want a sofa with this sort of styling but the advice I'm sure you'll receive from nearly any source is you'd be much better off building one with somewhat the same look from scratch, with project pieces scaled appropriately for the expected loads and purpose. And with joinery methods chosen from the outset to be strong enough and to last.

Comment: If this question survives, the soon-to-die link is of an Ikea Sundvik Crib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the answer to the question in the title is *yes, but not a good one*.

The crib is obviously made for a very lightweight occupant and the limited amount of strain they can introduce :-) and as such the scale of the pieces, and IMO very critically the way everything is fastened together, is based on this. The requirements for an adult-size single chair are far greater, much less a sofa expected to take two or more adults and all the shifting about they would do over the expected lifespan of the piece.

Accordingly, as I say in the Comments, I'm sure the advice you'll receive from nearly any source is that you'd be much better off building a sofa with similar styling from scratch so that:

- the main structural components are scaled appropriately for the expected loads and purpose;
- the joinery is chosen from the outset to be strong and durable enough (as in all conventional chairmaking).